# How to locate executable section

Tags: pe, executable

How to locate executable section in PE file?

Is there any of typical way to locate executable section in any PE file?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky i'am trying to know how to locate the programm executable section from pe

Comment: yes, but what do you plan to do next?

Comment: There could be more than one section with executable code, you will need to look at the characteristics for flag 0x20 (`IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE`)